# Gtk-rs: Set label within glib::timeout_add

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk-rs

I'm new to rust and having trouble with the scope of objects/variables in GTK. I have the following code, which works, but I need to set a label in the GTK Window to the text of the variable `watch_text`. Here is the code:

```
use adw::subclass::prelude::AdwApplicationWindowImpl;
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::subclass::prelude::*;
use gtk::{gio, glib, CompositeTemplate};
use glib::{clone, DateTime, timeout_add};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

    fn setup_signals(&self) {
            let imp = imp::FurWindow::from_instance(self);
            let running = Arc::new(Mutex::new(false));
    
            imp.start_button.connect_clicked(clone!(@weak self as this, @strong running => move |_| {
                if !*running.lock().unwrap() {
                    let mut secs: u32 = 0;
                    let mut mins: u32 = 0;
                    let mut hrs: u32 = 0;
                    this.inapp_notification("Starting Timer!");
                    *running.lock().unwrap() = true;
                    let stopwatch = DateTime::now_local();
                    let duration = Duration::new(1,0);
                    let timer_repeat = timeout_add(duration, clone!(@strong running as running_clone => move || {
                        if *running_clone.lock().unwrap() {
                            secs += 1;
                            if secs > 59 {
                                secs = 0;
                                mins += 1;
                                if mins > 59 {
                                    mins = 0;
                                    hrs += 1;
                                }
                            }
                            let watch_text: &str = &format!("{:02}:{:02}:{:02}", hrs, mins, secs).to_string();
                            println!("{}",watch_text);
                            // **Here the println works, everything prints correctly, 
                            // but I need to add watch_text to the label "watch" 
                            // this.set_watch_time(watch_text);
                        }
                        Continue(*running_clone.lock().unwrap())
                    }));
                } else {
                    this.inapp_notification("Stopping Timer!");
                    *running.lock().unwrap() = false;
                }
            }));
        }
```

The issue is that in the commented section, no matter how I try to access or clone imp.watch, I get an error `NonNull<GObject> cannot be sent between threads safely`. How can I set the label text to `watch_text`?

Comment: `clone!(@weak self as this)`? Are you using some undisclosed crate here?

Comment: @rodrigo I've updated the code to include the crates I'm using. This is just the `setup_signals` portion of the code from the GTK window.rs file that creates my window.

Comment: Ahh, `glib::clone!`, that I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [`timeout_add()`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/glib/source/fn.timeout_add.html) requires the passed callback to be `Send`, which is nice, because with this function you can pass values from one working thread to the GUI thread, to be processed and update the interface accordingly.

But GUI objects are not `Send`, because they live in the GUI thread and must be used only from the GUI thread, so they cannot be used for `timeout_add()`.

But that is precisely why there is this other [`timeout_add_local()`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/glib/source/fn.timeout_add_local.html), that works just like the other one, except that it does not require `Send`, and that it must be called from the GUI thread, or else it will panic.